# Is the Orange Guidance Soapstone item consumable?

Tags: dark-souls

I've seen that the first merchant found in *Undead Burg* is selling the *Orange Guidance Soapstone* item. The in-game description of the item is:

> Online play item.
>   Write/view/rate message.
>
> Messages transmit to other worlds, where they
>   are rated. Also, rate messages of others.
>
> In Lordran, the flow of time is distorted,
>   and messages allow Undead to assist
>   (or deceive) one another.

So, it appear that in contrast to *Demon's Souls*, I need this item to leave message to other players. What I'm wondering is whether or not this is a consumable item? Will I need to buy a new one each time I want to leave or rate a message?

And isn't the description misleading? Because, I've not yet bought it, but I'm already able to see some message on the ground.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not a consumable item, although you use it like one. That is to say you need to have it equipped in one of your item slots, and use it with the item-use button. So you could think of it was a consumable item with unlimited uses.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to equip it, like every other item. Equipping is just for quick use, but you can access it through the item screen.

And you only need one throughout the entire game.