# How do you provide hints in Dark Souls

Tags: dark-souls

In Demon Souls you could just press select (I think) and add your selected message. I would like to know how to do it though because I like everyone's help and feel bad at not being able to provide back.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In order to provide hints you'll need the [Orange Guidance Soapstone](http://darksoulswiki.wikispaces.com/Orange+Guidance+Soapstone):

[image]

You can buy this from the [Undead Merchant](http://darksouls.wikidot.com/undead-merchant-male) in the Undead Burg, near the first bonfire in the area, for 100 souls:

[image]

The soapstone behaves like a consumable item with an [unlimited number of uses](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/32985/is-the-orange-guidance-soapstone-item-consumable). So in order to use it you need to equip it to one of your item slots, than active it with "square" (on the PS3) to use it. This will give you the option to either write a message, delete one of your messages, or rate another users message.

Comment: So, to clarify, I don't need to buy a new one each time?

Comment: @danRhul You do not.

Comment: I believe its buy once, use forever.

Comment: The merchant also drops the soapstone if you decide to kill him for his Uchigatana. Also, you can quickly rate other people's hints by pressing the Back button (on the 360, probably Select on PS3).